# Script to email form to user dependent on form info

Tags: forms, email, google-apps-script, google-docs

Trying to create or edit a script that will tell google docs to send an e-mail containing form info to a specific individual if that individual's name is selected in the form.

any suggestions?

Comment: It seems that the FormEmailer script I developed will help you a lot: sites.google.com/site/formemailer

Comment: thanks alot. im going to try this out and i'll get back to you if i have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apps Script for that. There's a sample in the docs that shows how to send an email to a designated individual containing information captured by a Spreadsheet when a form is submitted:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_events#TriggerAttributes

Comment: Sorry, i'm not very experienced with this. I saw that you could do that, but is there a way to choose which individual gets e-mailed depending on the information submitted to the form. For instance if a student selects a teachers name as a part of the form, can the script be edited to email the submitted form to that teacher?

Comment: Using the e.values field shown in the link you can retrieve the value of the email they selected, and then send the email there.

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to understand, but I still can't wrap my head around how to actually set it up. It's easy enough to just copy and paste the script, but becuase I am not familiar with all of the terminology I am struggling to actually apply it. @EricKoleda

Comment: Try reading through more of the tutorials to get familiar with how the system works.

Comment: The issue now is that I am getting an error when I am trying to debug the code. (TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined.) @EricKoleda

Comment: That error indicates that the e object is not defined. This will be the case when you run the script in the editor, since there is no event passed.

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense. But then how come when I submit a form, the script isn't running. I set up a form that is literally just like the example from the tutorial but it isn't sending me the email. @EricKoleda

Comment: If there is an error in your script then it won't sent the email. You'll get an email later with the errors that happened. To debug it, create a test() function that creates a fake e variable with the values populates, and then call onFormSubmit(e). Then run test() in the script editor and look for errors.

Comment: could you suggest any other tutorials that reference a function that sends email to a designated individual captured by a Spreadsheet when a form is submitted? @EricKoleda

Comment: That's a very specific use case, so you won't find many tutorials on it. I just did a Hangout on Air last week on Google Apps Script, and my live coding demo covered handling a form submit: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2uLzJdEVCA

Comment: @EricKoleda Thanks for the help so far. This is where i'm at right now, but for some reason it is still not working. Do you see any glaring errors with this?

Comment: function contactUsMailer(e) {

  //  This script e-mails the contents of a form to a given recipient

  //  The form must have three fields in the order of: name; e-mail address; and message

  //  You must change the recipient variable below to your e-mail address

var recipient; 

  switch ( e.values[1] ) {

     case "Justin":

     recipient = "wousterman@gmail.com";

      break;

    var timestamp = e.values[0];

    var name = e.values[1];

    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient);
  } 
}

Comment: As mentioned, create a test function like the one below:

Comment: function test() {
  var e = { values: ['Justin', 'bob@example.com', 'Message'] };
  contactUsMailer(e);
}

Answer (score 0):

I have a way to do this using only spreadsheet functions, no GAS required. It works well, and I use it all the time.

But I have bills to pay and I am not convinced people will pay money for "Send Email" type innovations. So the error checking is not that great and there is no documentation.

If you are interested, let me know,. But because of the low quality and lack of docs, it would probably take you 2 hours to get it up and running.

Eddy Parkinson

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest you check out formMule, http://cloudlab.newvisions.org/scripts/formmule it can do exactly what you are asking, more info and a video http://youpd.org/formmule (note formmule was just recently updated so it looks slightly different then in the video.)

Good luck!